# No puedo crear una Vista en Google Analytics

Tags: vistas, google-analytics

Estoy tratando de crear una "Vista" en Google Analytics pero no me aparece la columna correspondiente. Hasta ahora he logrado crear el "Usuario" y dos "Propiedades" dependientes de este pero no encuentro la forma de crear las "Vistas" correspondientes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Google Analytics* está cambiando y resulta un poco confuso. Trataré de aclarártelo.

Hasta donde yo llego la evolución ha sido:

1. "Propiedad app + web" (fase Beta)
2. **"Universal Analytics" (*) (hasta 14-Oct-2020):** Se identifica porque el número de cuenta va precedido de "UA-" p.e. UA-123456789 (Atención, a veces no es muy evidente y tienes que crear un nuevo usuario para ver el prefijo UA). Esta opción sólo es apta para el seguimiento y análisis de páginas Web y tiene habilitada la opción de análisis mediante "Vistas". Si no la tuviera deberás:

   a) Crear una nueva "Propiedad"
   b) "Mostrar opciones avanzadas"
   c) Activar "Crear una Propiedad Analytics"
   d) Crear sólo una Propiedad "Universal Analytics"
3. **Google Analytics 4:** Se identifica porque el número de cuenta va precedido de "GA4-" (por ejemplo: GA4-123456789). En este caso el análisis ya nos se realiza mediante "Vistas" o "View" sino mediante "Flujo de Datos" o "Data Stream" (** incorporando una serie de mejoras) aunque Google ofrece la posibilidad de crear dos "Propiedades" una en formato UA con Vistas y otra en formato GA4 con Flujo de Datos.

En todos los casos hay que colocar el gtag correspondiente facilitado por *Google Analytics* dentro de la etiqueta  de la página que deseas analizar.

Fuentes:

(*) https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10089681?hl=es&utm_id=ad

(**) https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9216061?hl=es&utm_id=ad

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9367631

Comment: @padaleiana, bienvenido el consejo. Me está costando un poco aterrizar en esto. Es que, como no se muestra el like !!